Impossible to make space on full zfs pool
I have this zfs pool which seems to be full because of some reservations
# zpool get all data2
NAME   PROPERTY                       VALUE                          SOURCE
data2  size                           128T                           -
data2  capacity                       68%                            -
data2  free                           40.9T                          -
data2  allocated                      87.1T                          -

# zfs get all data2
NAME   PROPERTY              VALUE                      SOURCE
data2  used                  97.1T                      -
data2  available             0B                         -
data2  referenced            238K                       -
data2  usedbysnapshots       238K                       -
data2  usedbydataset         238K                       -
data2  usedbychildren        97.1T                      -
data2  usedbyrefreservation  0B                         -
data2  written               18.3K                      -
data2  logicalused           65.9T                      -
data2  logicalreferenced     46K                        -

It contains a lot of datasets among them I have two datasets, A and B, which are empty, with 3 snapshots, also empty.
# zfs get all data2/groups/A
NAME                         PROPERTY              VALUE                         SOURCE
data2/groups/A  used                  100G                          -
data2/groups/A  available             100G                          -
data2/groups/A  referenced            219K                          -
data2/groups/A  reservation           none                          local
data2/groups/A  refreservation        100G                          local
data2/groups/A  usedbysnapshots       402K                          -
data2/groups/A  usedbydataset         219K                          -
data2/groups/A  usedbychildren        0B                            -
data2/groups/A  usedbyrefreservation  100G                          -
data2/groups/A  written               128K                          -
data2/groups/A  logicalused           128K                          -
data2/groups/A  logicalreferenced     42K                           -

# zfs get all data2/logins/B
NAME                   PROPERTY              VALUE                     SOURCE
data2/logins/B  used                  512K                      -
data2/logins/B  available             1024G                     -
data2/logins/B  referenced            219K                      -
data2/logins/B  reservation           1T                        local
data2/logins/B  refreservation        none                      default
data2/logins/B  usedbysnapshots       292K                      -
data2/logins/B  usedbydataset         219K                      -
data2/logins/B  usedbychildren        0B                        -
data2/logins/B  usedbyrefreservation  0B                        -
data2/logins/B  written               146K                      -
data2/logins/B  logicalused           102K                      -
data2/logins/B  logicalreferenced     42K                       -

My problem is that I cannot remove anything to make some free space
# zfs destroy data2/groups/A@yesterday
internal error: cannot destroy snapshots: Channel number out of range
Aborted (core dumped)
# zfs set refreservation=none data2/groups/A
cannot set property for 'data2/groups/A': size is greater than available space
# zfs destroy data2/groups/B@yesterday
internal error: cannot destroy snapshots: Channel number out of range
Aborted (core dumped)
# zfs set reservation=none data2/logins/B
cannot set property for 'data2/logins/B': size is greater than available space

It seems related to https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9849, setting spa_slop_shift to 6 did not help.
If any of you have an idea that does not involve moving 100T from a dataset to another (that I don't have) I would be very happy.
# uname -a
Linux stockage 4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 14 14:20:09 EDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# modinfo zfs | grep -iw version
version:        2.1.15-1

